# SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Database Engine Shared: The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, uninstallation

Previously, I had downloaded SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Service (so that it includes SQL Server Management Studio).  Now I want to uninstall this application.  When I attempted to perform this, I received the following error:

```
SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Database Engine Shared

The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.

Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'sql_engine_core_shared.msi' in the box below.
```

The sql_engine_core_shared.msi cannot be found anywhere on my machine.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Have done a lot of searching with no success.  TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the original exe that I had downloaded, and when it starts it unpacks a bunch of files into a GUID-named folder on the C drive:

```
SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
```

At some point later this file is deleted, which is why I could no longer find the required MSI file.  So all I did to resolve the issue was start that exe, then copy all the files in that directory to a different location so they don't get deleted.  Then, when I run the installer, and that dialog comes up I pointed the directory to my backup location and the uninstall completed successfully, e.g.,

```
C:\MySqlServerInstallBackup\1033_enu_lp\x64\setup
```

HTH.